# Build a project

Tags: java, web-applications, build

I never worked on ANT or MAVEN, I always built my projects with two folders EAR and WAR
Now I am asked to build the project in three folder/modules

project-EAR
project-WAR
project

EAR will contain deployment descriptor application.xml
WAR will contain WebContent
prject will contain src/java folder

can anyone help me build using RAD/Eclipse or guide me where to start simple and quick.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans IDE can autogenerate ant build scripts.

Comment: Right-click project->Export->General->Ant Buildfiles